# What are the different ways of constructing cv::Mat?

Tags: opencv

OpenCV Version 3.2.0

I am reading Bradski and trying to make Different cv::Mat constructors - single channel.
Can someone please tell, why the constructors do not work?

```
float data1[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
float data2[6] = {10,20,30,40,50,60};
float data3[6] = {100,200,300,400,500,600};

cv::Mat mat1(3,4,CV_32FC1); //OK
cv::Mat mat2(3,4,CV_32FC1,cv::Scalar(33.3)); //OK
cv::Mat mat3(3,4,CV_32FC1,data1,sizeof(float)); //OK
cv::Mat mat4(cv::Size(3,4),CV_32FC1); //OK
cv::Mat mat5(cv::Size(3,4),CV_32FC1,cv::Scalar(66.6)); //OK
cv::Mat mat6(cv::Size(3,4),CV_32FC1,data2,sizeof(float)); //OK
int sz[] = {8, 8, 8};
cv::Mat bigCube1(3, sz, CV_32FC1); // OK
cv::Mat bigCube2(3, sz, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar::all(99)); // OK 
cv::Mat bigCube3(3, sz, CV_32FC1, data3, 4); // Not OK, How to initialise a 3D from data?
std::cout << mat1 << std::endl << mat2 << std::endl << mat3 << std::endl << mat4 << std::endl << mat5 << std::endl << mat6 << std::endl; // OK                                                                   
std::cout << bigCube1.at<float>(10,10,10)  << std::endl << bigCube2.at<float>(10,10,10) << std::endl; // OK

cv::Mat img_rgb = cv::imread("lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
std::vector<cv::Range> ranges(3, cv::Range(2,3));

cv::Mat roiRange( img_rgb, cv::Range(100, 300), cv::Range(0, 512)); //OK
cv::Mat roiRect( img_rgb, cv::Rect(0,100,512,200)); // OK
cv::Mat roiRangeMultiple( bigCube1, ranges); // OK

cv::namedWindow("range", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("range", roiRange);  // OK
cv::namedWindow("rect", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("rect", roiRect); // OK
std::cout << roiRangeMultiple.at<float>(0,1,1); // Not OK. Expecting a float value as answer
cv::waitKey(0);
```

The corresponding answers are:

```
[4.6634629e-10, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0;
 127.62516, 2.8025969e-45, 0, 0]

[33.299999, 33.299999, 33.299999, 33.299999;
 33.299999, 33.299999, 33.299999, 33.299999;
 33.299999, 33.299999, 33.299999, 33.299999]

[1, 2, 3, 4;
 2, 3, 4, 5;
 3, 4, 5, 6]

[0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0]

[66.599998, 66.599998, 66.599998;
 66.599998, 66.599998, 66.599998;
 66.599998, 66.599998, 66.599998;
 66.599998, 66.599998, 66.599998]

[10, 20, 30;
 20, 30, 40;
 30, 40, 50;
 40, 50, 60]
 0  // bigCube1
 99 // bigCube2
```

And then the corresponding answers for lena.jpg is the cropped version from Range and Rect. I dont know how to use the ranges though.

Comment: `mat3` and `mat6` don't seem to be OK. At least OpenCV 3.x [requires](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L512) the step size to be at least the length of a row (i.e. no overlap is allowed).

Comment: @DanMašek It works. The result is in the answer. sizeof(float) steps by one element in the source array. It does not have to be the sizeof(row)

Comment: [That assert](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2.2/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L141) has been there at least since OpenCV 2.2. Of course, since it's a `CV_DbgAssert`, it will only fire in debug mode, and in release mode it will "work". However, something that crashes and burns in debug mode is not something I'd call working.

Comment: bigcube1 seems to be compiling in my computer. What do you mean with Not Ok? compiles? runs? gives error? which error?

Comment: Also note that the formatting function used by `operator<<` only [support at most 2-dimensional arrays](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/out.cpp#L86).

Comment: @DanMašek : that was the key ! I have changed my question a little bit and removed the std::cout. Now theres only 2 things that arent working.

Comment: @api55 : have made some changes in the original question. bigCube1 is also working now.. the problem was with the std::cout as pointed by Dan. However, there are 2 not oks now.

Comment: @DanMašek changed to CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug and still I dont get any assert. How is CV_DbgAsset triggered?

Comment: @infoclogged The symbol `_DEBUG` needs to be defined. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp#L421

Comment: @infoclogged OK, hopefully the answer covers everything.

Answer (score -1):

Multiple issues.

```
cv::Mat mat3(3,4,CV_32FC1,data1,sizeof(float));
```

This will crash in debug mode, failing [an assertion](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp#L476). Even though this is not in the documentation, the step size must be at least the length of a row (i.e. no overlap is allowed).

The correct code for this scenario would be something like.

```
float data1[12] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
cv::Mat mat3(3, 4, CV_32FC1, data1, 4 * sizeof(float));
```

---

```
cv::Mat mat6(cv::Size(3,4),CV_32FC1,data2,sizeof(float));
```

Similar situation as in previous case. Also note that this produces a differently shaped array -- previous was 3 rows, 4 columns, this one has 4 rows and 3 columns (see [docs of cv::Size](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d6/d50/classcv_1_1Size__.html#a45c97e9a4930d73fde11c2acc5f371ac)).

```
float data2[12] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 20, 30, 40, 50, 30, 40, 50, 60 };
cv::Mat mat6(cv::Size(3, 4), CV_32FC1, data2, 3 * sizeof(float));
```

---

```
cv::Mat bigCube1(3, sz, CV_8UC1);
std::cout << bigCube1 << std::endl;
```

Formatting of arrays with more than 2 dimensions is [not supported](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0/modules/core/src/out.cpp#L86).

You can test that the array was correctly created by manually printing all the values:

```
for (auto const& v : cv::Mat1b(bigCube2)) {
    std::cout << uint(v) << " ";
}
std::cout << "\n";
```

---

```
cv::Mat bigCube3(3, sz, CV_32FC1, data3, 4);
```

The problem here is the last parameter. From [the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a5fafc033e089143062fd31015b5d0f40)

> ```
> cv::Mat::Mat(int ndims,
>     const int *   sizes,
>     int type,
>     void * data,
>     const size_t * steps = 0 
>     )
> ```
>
> **steps** - Array of ndims-1 steps in case of a multi-dimensional array (the last step is always set to the element size). If not specified, the matrix is assumed to be continuous.

- You're not passing an array of steps as the last parameter (only a single integer)
- you don't pass enough data
- and the rows would again overlap.

One way to do this would be something like

```
float data3[8 * 8 * 8];
// Populate the data with sequence 0..511
std::iota(std::begin(data3), std::end(data3), 0.0f);

int sz[] = { 8, 8, 8 };
size_t steps[] = { 8 * 8 * sizeof(float), 8 * sizeof(float) };
cv::Mat bigCube3(3, sz, CV_32FC1, data3, steps);
```

---

```
cv::Mat bigCube1(3, sz, CV_8UC1);
// ...
std::cout << roiRangeMultiple.at<float>(0,1,1); // Not OK. Expecting a float value as answer
```

The data type is `CV_8UC1`, so each element is an unsigned char. That means you shouldn't be extracting `float` values from it. Your expectation is incorrect. (Now I see you changed the code in your question).

Also, note that with [`cv::Range`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d35/classcv_1_1Range.html) "start is an inclusive left boundary of the range and end is an exclusive right boundary of the range". Since you extract `cv::Range(2,3)` in each axis, the resulting `Mat` is 1 x 1 x 1. Hence, you're accessing elements out of range (again, this would trigger a debug mode assertion).

```
std::cout << roiRangeMultiple.at<unsigned char>(0,0,0);
```

After the change you have the correct type. However notice that you never initialize `bigCube1`. You most likely get a 0.0f as a result, which will print as `0`. You can try this yourself, just execute `std::cout << 0.0f;` and see.

Comment: I will go thru it. Looks like I need a complete recompile of OpenCV with _DEBUG right?

Comment: Ya, you need a debug build of OpenCV.

Comment: I think I dont need a CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug in this case. Just passing the _DEBUG to the source files during compilation should work, right? I mean, I dont want to debug opencv, but just activate the assert. However, I cant find any corresponding _DEBUG option in the cmake file.. Can you please tell me how did you do it?

Comment: I just a have a debug build of OpenCV around, that I use with debug builds of my code (Since I'm using MSVC++, it's kind of a necessity anyway). Basically like what you'd get with `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` set to `Debug`.

Comment: just a small hint, as your comments were a little misleading.  CV_DbgAssert () neither require debug symbols from opencv, nor the application code. Its enough to pass _DEBUG macro during the compilation of the application code.